# Error on create Release from build

Tags: tfs, build, release-management, ms-release-management

I am trying setup Release Management with TFS 2013 using build template "ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml" but when I set up to carry out the release occurs the following error:

"ERROR: The account running the TFS build service (Domain\User) needs to be added to the system user in the Release Management Server."

The RM is installed on isolated server from the server that is configured Build Controller, however, the machines are within the same domain, and each server has its own user with administator permission to perform the services.

The build server user was added among users of services in RM, and the error continues to occur.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that listed in the RM Client under the users list is the account used by the build server? And that it is marked as a Service?

Comment: Yes, i opened Release Management Client click on Administration —> Management Users created a new user and mark like User Service

Comment: Domain account or local account?

Comment: Domain, but has permissions like local administrator

Comment: I would raise it as a bug on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Did you restart the RM service after adding the user? Not sure that would help but you never know.

Comment: Yes, i rebooted the server and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that the Release Management **client** needs to be installed on the machine(s) running the build agent. This gem is hidden away on p26 of the [current RM user guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/B/29B10D38-3473-4AC2-9CEB-7D471E0A8ECD/Release%20Management%20for%20Visual%20Studio%202013%20User%20Guide.pdf). This won't be a problem for anyone with everything on one server but will need addressing where components are distributed.